# Jitter calculation in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I have a query regarding the Jitter calculation method in Wireshark.

Wireshark calculates jitter according to RFC3550 (RTP):

If Si is the RTP timestamp from packet i, and Ri is the time of arrival in RTP timestamp units for packet i, then for two packets i and j, D may be expressed as

**D(i,j) = (Rj - Ri) - (Sj - Si) = (Rj - Sj) - (Ri - Si)**

The interarrival jitter SHOULD be calculated continuously as each data packet i is received from source SSRC_n, using this difference D for that packet and the previous packet i-1 in order of arrival (not necessarily in sequence), according to the formula

**J(i) = J(i-1) + (|D(i-1,i)| - J(i-1))/16**

Now, here the absolute value of inter-arrival jitter has been taken into consideration. My query is why the absolute value has been taken when the jitter could be negative also and i think if we take the negative jitter into consideration also, we will get the much actual value rather than the value we are taking at present

Also, when we plot the jitter distribution graph using the above method, it wont be centered around zero as we have made all the values positive and that graph wont look realistic.

Can someone clarify my query?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a good [definition of jitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter):

> Jitter is the undesired deviation from true periodicity of an assumed
>   periodic signal...

A jitter value of zero means the signal has no variation from the expected value. As the variation increases (the packets are getting bunched up and spread out) the jitter increases in magnitude.

The bunching and spreading are really the same effect; bunching in one place causes spreading in another so this 'bunching and spreading' doesn't have a direction, just a magnitude.

I hope this helps - it was the best explanation I could come up with.

Comment: i agree to this but i think it does not clear my query which is, why the absolute value has been taken when the jitter could be negative also.

Comment: Because the jitter would average to zero

Comment: but then it wont show the real jitter as there wont be negative jitter thereafter using the absolute value and we wont get the exact jitter and it will be a cumulative value of all instantaneous jitter values for each packets.

Comment: Because RTP is for 'real time' transport i.e. the notion of a packet arriving early would mean that it would contain data that hasn't been generated yet.  So, negative jitter doesn't fit into the scenario.  Either a packet is on-time, or it is late.  It can't be early.  However, due to latency in the stream, a packet might arrive sooner than expected, in relation to delivery of other packets.